# the_content() Returns post content when I want page content

Tags: pages, the-content

I'm very new to WordPress, but I'm currently doing work on a site built on the platform. I'm making my way through, but I've run into a bit of a problem.

I'm trying to add content from the text editor of the site's blog `page`, which uses the standard index.php template. However, when I use `<?php the_content(); ?>` like other pages use, it returns the content of the latest `post`. Is there a way to get the content from the page editor instead?

I've been looking all morning without really finding anything satisfactory. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

```
            <section id="primary" >
                <?php the_content(); ?>
                <div class="content" role="main" data-target="index" >

                    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

                        <?php get_template_part('inc/loop', get_post_type() ); ?>

                    <?php else : ?>

                        <?php get_template_part('inc/content', 'none' ); ?>

                    <?php endif; ?>

                </div><!-- end content -->
            </section><!-- end primary -->
```

Comment: This [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/) is invaluable to all WordPress'ers new and old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you configure your blog (posts) page under Settings > Reading, that page becomes nothing more than a placeholder - in other words, you won't be able to grab it's title/content within `index.php` without a little trickery:

```
if ( $page_id = get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) ) {
    echo get_the_title( $page_id );

    // the_content() doesn't accept a post ID parameter
    if ( $post = get_post( $page_id ) ) {
        setup_postdata( $post ); //  "posts" page is now current post for most template tags        
        the_content();
        wp_reset_postdata(); // So everything below functions as normal
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to set a page as the home page rather than a post. You can set this using wordpress settings. You have to set a selected page that will display on the site's home.

- Login to admin end and go to `Settings` -> `Reading`
- Select the 2nd option (A static page) for the setting `Front page displays`
- Then select the page from the dropdown list for `Front page` whichever you want to set as the home page.
- Save the settings.

Now if you check your site, you should see a page rather than post.